# Git archive removes .ebextensions on the final zip output

Tags: git, symfony, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a AWS ELB app. And Im archiving the whole symfony2 project using the command : `git archive --format=zip HEAD > test.zip`

But it's weird coz the final output doesn't include the `.ebextensions` folder which resulted to a `severe` health. Did I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is .ebextensions folder hidden by your OS? ie. If using Windows, do you have 'Show hidden folders/files' enabled?  Additionally, do you have 'Show file extensions for known types' enabled?

Comment: No it's not hidden. And yes I have em enabled. :/ Weird right?

Comment: Definitely... Try making another .whatever folder and zipping that up with it and see what happens.

Comment: I am thinking that git is ignoring the folder or not seeing it.  This is coming down from the repository, or a local changeset?

Comment: did you check the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @zackery.fix from a local changeset.

Comment: @Tal `.ebextensions` wasn't on the `.gitignore`

Comment: Are any files inside .ebextensions in .gitignore?

Comment: Does .ebextensions reside in HEAD?  I think the files inside .ebextensions are ignored making the folder empty, or some pattern is defined in .gitignore that omits it...

Comment: @zackery.fix I think that's it, .ebextensions is not it the HEAD. OMG. What I temporary did is drag  and dropped the .ebextensions folder to the archived file.

Comment: @zackery.fix "Are any files inside .ebextensions in .gitignore?" None.

Comment: Figured it out?  I'm confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion :**

Based on **@zackery.fix's** comment. I would like to share a simple solution for this problem. In my case the `.ebextensions` folder is not on the HEAD of the repo, I just pasted the `.ebextensions` from another source to the local copy of that repo that I have. I think that's the reason why the command `git archive --format=zip HEAD > test.zip` excluded the `.ebextensions` because it is not in the HEAD so it was excluded upon archiving.

**Solution 1:**

1. Commit the `.ebextensions` folder to the repo HEAD.
2. Perform the archiving through `git` one more time.

**Solution 2:**

This may not be the best solution, but it worked for me.

1. I performed the command `git archive --format=zip HEAD > test.zip` which created a zip/rar file namd **test.rar/test.zip**.
2. Open that **test.rar/test.zip** file. Drop the `.ebextensions` folder here and update that zip file. 
   [image]

Comment: That makes sense.  I honestly didn't want to ask that because I assumed HEAD had the folder. ^.^

Comment: @zackery.fix Im glad it make sense now :D Thanks for the help :)